# Decimal literals in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal

I want that the result will be 0.5 when `@test` is 0. But it seems, that the result is always an INT.

```
DECLARE @test INT = 0
SELECT
ISNULL(NULLIF(@test, 0.0), 0.5)
```

The result is

[image]

But I want to have 0.5.

Is this possible to do without a `CAST`?

Comment: "I have an apple. why isn't it acting like an orange?". If you want 0.5, then you can't use an int.

Comment: without a `CAST`?, either declare the variable as a `DECIMAL` or perform a multiplication? `ISNULL(NULLIF(@test*1.0, 0.0), 0.5)`?. Either way, it would be better to just use `CAST`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) & [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) return a value of the first type. In your case, `@test` is an INT, so your `NULLIF()` returns an INT, and so does `ISNULL()`.

You can reverse the order of your values in the `NULLIF` call, since INT is convertible to REAL, and you'll get your result:

```
DECLARE @test INT = 0
SELECT
ISNULL(NULLIF(0.0, @test), 0.5)
```